# Symfony, configure firewall to grant access to authenticated and anonymous users

Tags: security, symfony

How can I configure security **firewalls** and **access_control** so that all pages render limited information for anonymous users (note login is not enforced), but shows full details for authenticated users?

```
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_AGENT: ROLE_USER

providers:
    agent_provider:
        memory:
            users:
                agent: { password: agentpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_AGENT' ] }
    user_provider:
        memory:
            users:
                user:  { password: userpass, roles: [ 'ROLE_USER' ] }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
        anonymous: true
    agent_area:
        provider: agent_provider
        pattern:   ^/agent
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: agent_login
            check_path: agent_login_check
            default_target_path: /agent
        logout:
            path:   agent_logout
            target: /agent
    user_area:
        provider: user_provider
        pattern:   ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: app_login
            check_path: app_login_check
            default_target_path: /
        logout:
            path:   app_logout
            target: /

access_control:
    - { path: ^/agent/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/agent, roles: ROLE_AGENT }
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

If the last two lines from **access_control** are removed, the login process appears to work as expected, but is_granted('ROLE_USER') always return false even when a user is logged in.

```
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER }
```

Comment: these are actually two questions. i answered the one on the top asking how to render different/extended contents for different user roles ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use twig's **is_granted()** function to show different content to users and guests.

```
{% if is_granted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY') %}

    {# ... only non logged-in users content ... #}

{% endif %}
```

... or ...

```
{% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}

   {# .. user's content ... #}

{% endif %}
```